# Dynamically remove select option value using href - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a list of users with `delete` hyperlink assume

```
<a href="#" onclick="delete(id)">Delete</a>
```

And i have a combo box at the top to filter specific user using user id.

The delete action will performed with ajax and it reloads the content. The content gets reloaded but the combo box contains the deleted id. Is there any way to clear it using jquery.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried.

Comment: Please include your code, or just add it in jsfiddle and give us the link

Answer (score 1):

You can remove an option like

```
$("#selectBox option[value='option1']").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes,If you know the value which you want to delete,

Try

```
$("#selectionid option[value='deletedUser']").remove();
```

Note:Do it in Ajax success function

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
    $(function delete(id) {
      $('#my-select option[value="'+ id +'"]').remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here first you get the element in jQuery selector through id or class the find the option which you want to delete or remove.. like if  first element then eq(0), if second then eq(1) and so on.. then remove function to remove value

```
   $('#Combobox_id').find("option").eq(0).remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$( "#myselect option:selected" ).remove();  // because your deleted user id will be selected
```